# Facebook phonegap login

Tags: facebook, cordova, authentication

I am trying to log in with Facebook using PhoneGap.  It seems to works well.
But on iOS 6.0, the login failed with the message "The operation couldn't be completed.(com.facebook.sdk error 5)".

If I don't set the account in setting of my iPhone, the plugin logged in using browser.
There is no problem.
But if I set the account in the setting, it shows upon message.
If I close the app, and launch again, it logs in successfully.

This function checks whether logged in already.

```
function getLoginStatus() {    
FB.getLoginStatus(function(session) {
    console.log('Got the user\'s session(facebook): ', session);

    if (session.status == 'connected') {
        FB.api('/me', {
            fields: 'id, name, email'
        },
        function(response) {
            if (response.error) { 
               console.log('get user name failed');
               login(); // login to Facebook.
            }
            else
            {                   
               console.log('FB name, ' + response.name);
               console.log('FB id, ' + response.id);
               console.log('FB email, ' + response.email);

               siteLogin(response); // login to my site.                   
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log('get user name failed 2');

        login(); // login to Facebook
    }

});
}
```

Facebook login function

```
function login() {
FB.login(
         function(response) {

         if (response.session) {
             alert('logged in');
         } else {
             alert('not logged in');
         }
    },
    { scope: "email" }
);
}
```

This is the event function.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login',  function(response) {      
FB.api('/me',{ fields: 'id, name, email' }, function(response1) {        
       if (response1.name !== undefined)
       {   
            siteLogin(response1);    // login to my site.            
       }
       else
       {
            // I think here I get the message "The operation couldn't be completed.(com.facebook.sdk error 5)"
            alert('error.');
       }
});
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576977/is-there-any-facebook-plugin-for-phonegap-2-7-0/16579592#16579592